# How to count null values and nonull values with 0 and 1 as row indexs not False and True in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I get some code as followed:

```
train_df['Age'].isnull().value_counts()
```

```
False    714
True     177
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

So I am wondering how to count null values and nonnull values with 0 and 1 as row index not False and True in Pandas, which should output as followed:

```
0    714
1    177
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

I know maybe I can generate a new DataFrame and change the row index, but it seems like complex.
So could anyone help me and give me a concise way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
train_df['Age'].isnull().astype(int).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also assign whatever index you like, e.g. if you have

```
s = train_df['Age'].isnull().value_counts()
```

Then

```
s.index = s.index.astype(int)
```